# Relative pose optimization using 5-point algorithm and RANSAC

Tags: opencv, 3d-reconstruction, multiview, pose-estimation

I am trying to get 3D reconstruction from uncalibrated multi-view images.
I don't know the intrinsic parameters of the camera

I have SIFT features.

What I like to do is filtering out-liers using the 5-point algorithm in combination with RANSAC, so that I can proceed for the relative pose optimization and triangulation of the points matched.

Opencv has one API
findEssentialMat(); That API needs focal and pp. Where I can have focal and pp?
Is this API findEssentialMat() the right one I have to use for the pose estimation?
If my approach is wrong, is there any API closer to what I want to achieve in OpenCV?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know the intrinsic parameters of the camera. [...]
>
> [...] proceed [with] the relative pose optimization and triangulation of the points matched.
>
> Where I can have focal and pp?

Then `findEssentialMat()` can not be used in this situation as it requires the intrinsic parameters, which are the focal length and principal point (`focal` and `pp` arguments).

First calibrate the camera to recover these parameters. Then pose estimation and 3D triangulation will be possible using OpenCV functions.